# Need help in Python multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I'm new to python and need your help in this issue. Tried looking everywhere but didn't find any working solution.

My code is:

```
a=input("Enter a number : ")
b=10
c=a*b
print("Multiply =",c)
```

The output I'm getting for `a=2` is:

```
Multiply = 2222222222
```

I want it to print `Multiply = 20` but instead it is printing 10 times the digit 1, but I want the product. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

By default, `input()` returns a string. Using

```
a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply a string. I like to think of it as `10*'word'`. Possible but won't get you an output.

```
a=int(input("Enter a number : "))
b=10
c=a*b
print("Multiply =",c)
```

Take an int input.

Comment: You can multiply a string though. It'll just repeat the string `b` amount of times, which is what happened to the asker.

Comment: Yes I know.I said this is possible. But your output is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the input to an integer using something like `int(input("Enter a number : "))` but if the input is not an integer that will cause issues.

To make sure the input is a string I recommend something like this:

```
while True:
    a = input("Enter a number : ")
    if a.isnumeric():
        a = int(a)
        break
    print("You did not input a number.")
    
b = 10
c = a * b
print("Multiply =",c)
```

This will loop until the user gives a number.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use `float` to add integer or float as input.

```
print("Multiply =", float(input("Enter a number : "))*10)
```

```
int1: 5
int2: 5.5
out1: 50.0
out2: 55.0
```

Or:

```
print("Multiply =", int(float(input("Enter a number : "))*10))
```

```
int1: 5
int2: 5.5
out1: 50
out2: 55
```

Answer (score 0):

Input takes string. So first of all convert it to integer by calling int() function

```
a = int(input("Enter a number : "))
b = 10
c = a*b
print("Multiply =",c)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remember in python input() function always returns string so when you need any certain data type as your input type cast accordingly, Here are few Examples**

```
x = int(input()) # input 20 

print(x)  -> prints 20 

x = float(input()) # input 50 
 
print(x)  -> prints 50.0

x = list(map(int, input().split(' '))) # input 20 30 40 as integer 

print(x)  -> prints list [20, 30, 40]

so the solution for your question is:
 
a=int(input("Enter a number : "))
b=10
c=a*b
print("Multiply =",c)
```